# Oracle ADF 12c to be run on JBoss EAP 6.2

Tags: oracle, jboss, oracle-adf, jboss6.x

I would like to know whether Oracle ADF 12c can be run on JBoss EAP 6.2 or not ? I have checked Oracle ADF 12c doc and it mentions only JBoss 5.

Comment: I'm sure the answer you've received on [Oracle Community](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3560105) answered your question already.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why not.  I have jboss 6.1 running with hibernate 4.2.15 and Oracle 12c.